# How to make corutine wait for download (Unity android)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When the application first time starts I need to download a file 100mb. In order to do it I use such approach:

```
    protected void Start()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(toCopy))
        {
            StartCoroutine(CopyFile(fromCopy, toCopy));
        }
...
    }

    IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(from);

        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        byte[] yourBytes = www.bytes;

        File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
    }
```

But my application crashed and downloaded file actually has size - 0kb. So, I assume that corutine starts downloading, but there is no wait and further in code I try to use this file, but it actually has not been downloaded so I get crash.

Question is - how to make corutine in this case to wait until file will be downloaded?

**EDIT**

I change my code thanks @derHugo

```
    IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to)
    {
        using (var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(from))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            if (uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Unity Download error :: {uwr.responseCode} - {uwr.error}!", this);
                yield break;
            }

            byte[] yourBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;

            File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
        }
    }

protected void Start()
{
...
        if (!File.Exists(toCopy))
        {
            StartCoroutine(CopyFile(fromCopy, toCopy));
        }

        useCoiedFileByPath(toCopy); <-------------- //Can I to be sure that on this line file has alredy copied and available to use?

...
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
    protected IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unity Begin");

#if !UNITY_ANDROID
        if (!clipFile.Contains("\\"))
        {
            string resFolder = Path.GetFullPath(Application.streamingAssetsPath);
            clipFile = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(resFolder, clipFile));
        }
#endif

        Debug.LogError("Unity Before copy");
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string fromCopy = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, clipFile);
        string toCopy = Application.persistentDataPath + "/copiedfile.tet";
        Debug.LogError($"Unity HERE path from copy :: {fromCopy}, to copy :: {toCopy}");

        if (!File.Exists(toCopy)) 
        {
            yield return CopyFile(fromCopy, toCopy);
            //StartCoroutine(CopyFile(fromCopy, toCopy));
        }
#endif

        Debug.LogError("Unity After copy");

        register_debug_callback_default();
        stream_set_progiling_debug_messages(true);

#if UNITY_ANDROID
        clipFile = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + clipFile;
#endif

        if (File.Exists(clipFile))
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Path to file :: {clipFile}");
            CreateStreamDecoder();
            stream_init_model(stream, clipFile);
        }
        else
        {
            stream = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        meshRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshRenderer.material = new Material(GetShader());
        meshFilter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        FramePlaying = 0;

        Debug.LogError("Unity End");

        yield return null;
    }

    IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to)
    {
        using (var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(from))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            if (uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Unity Download error :: {uwr.responseCode} - {uwr.error}!", this);
                yield break;
            }

            byte[] yourBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;

            File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Www is deprecated however you dont ever seem to request it. You get the object ready but dont seem to request anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik this should work

```
IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to)
{
    using(var www = new WWW(from))
    {
        yield return www;
        // though it should behave the same as
        //while(!www.isDone) yield return null;
        // or also
        //yield return new WaitUntil(() => www.isDone);

        byte[] yourBytes = www.bytes;

        File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
    }
}
```

However, in general [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) is **obsolete** and has no real check for any errors on the way. So you might just have a hidden error due to a missing file location resulting in an empty `byte[]`.

You should probably rather use [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html)

```
IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to)
{
    using(var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(from))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendRequest();

        if(uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
        {
             Debug.LogError($"Download error {uwr.responseCode} - {uwr.error}!", this);
            yield break;
        }

        byte[] yourBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;

        File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
    }
}
```

---

The thing is: It is completely unclear in your use case at which point exactly your app crashes and what leads to that crash.

---

**UPDATE**

Now that we know your actual issue: **Nope!** You can not be sure since starting a Coroutine will not delay the later code lines. The `useCoiedFilePath` will be executed immediately.

If you wan to be sure there are at least three possible ways to go:

A) Simply make the `Start` a Coroutine itself. Yes this is possible and probably the favorite for your use case

```
protected IEnumerator Start()
{
    ...

    if (!File.Exists(toCopy))
    {
        yield return CopyFile(fromCopy, toCopy));
    }

    useCoiedFileByPath(toCopy); 

    ...
}
```

This simply delays everything in the end of `Start` until the download is done.

B) Move the to be delayed code into the routine

```
protected void Start()
{
    ...

    StartCoroutine(CopyFile(fromCopy, toCopy));
}

IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to)
{
    if(!File.Exists(to))
    {
        using (var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(from))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            if (uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Unity Download error : {uwr.responseCode} - {uwr.error}!", this);
                yield break;
            }

            byte[] yourBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;

            File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
        }
    }

    useCoiedFileByPath(toCopy);
    ...
}
```

Note though how this copy routine now becomes quite inflexible since the check for existence and reaction is already included so this can't be reused later to simply copy another file.

C) Use a callback event like

```
IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to, Action whenDone)
{
    using (var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(from))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Unity Download error :: {uwr.responseCode} - {uwr.error}!", this);
            yield break;
        }

        byte[] yourBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;

        File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
    }

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}

protected void Start()
{
    ...

    if (!File.Exists(toCopy))
    {
        StartCoroutine(CopyFile(fromCopy, toCopy, () => 
        {
            useCoiedFileByPath(toCopy)));

            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        useCoiedFileByPath(toCopy);

        ...
    }
}
```

This is more flexible than `B` but note how you have to kind of double implement the reaction.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question and there is a comment line `Can I to be sure that on this line file has alredy copied and available to use?`. Could you please take a look

Comment: Saw the edit and the answer is: Nope of course not! Starting a Coroutine will not delay any code lines after it. If you want to be sure move that into the coroutine

Comment: First option really the most match to what I need. I changed my `Start()` method to implementation you gave in your answer, but it doesn't work. Looks like that `Start()` don't invokes... Are you sure that `protected void Start()` and `protected IEnumerator Start()` invokes by system in the same way?

Comment: Not in the same way but yes it should. See e.g. [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html). If `Start` returns `IEnumerator` Unity automatically starts it as a Coroutine instead

Comment: hmm, I still could not find what is the problem. I edited my question. Could you please take a look if it looks ok ? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you get the first error log? Did you try to not make it an error but only a normal log or warning? .. not sure but LogError might cause the later code not being executed

Comment: No, problem not in log. Ok, do you think there is a way to invoke this Copy method without corutines? Such way copy will be executed in the main thread and I'll be sure that all next lines will be executed after file was copied. Yes/no?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Coroutines are always in the main thread ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to yield return your www class after implementing a class and after that try to yield return new  waitUntil(()=>www.isDone)

Comment: Could you please provide an code example? I am new in C# Unity, not sure I got what you meant